# Cannot disable CompactStrings Java 9 using Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jvm-arguments, java-9

I am trying to disable the CompactStrings feature of Java 9 using the VM option: `-XX:-CompactStrings`, but it does not work.

When I tried to debug my application, the `COMPACT_STRINGS` variable in `String` class is always true (with or without the VM option)

I have the latest version of Java 9: jdk-9+181
And the Netbeans IDE Build 201709070001

I tried various options to set the VM option and **none of them works**.

What I tried is: 
**setting the VM option in app.conf, setting it in project.properties, running netbeans by ./netbeans -XX:-CompactStrings, setting the JVM option in Project->Properties->Run->VM Options**

[image]

Is this a bug in Netbeans? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to start your _application_ with that option, not NetBeans itself. When you run your project, NetBeans starts a new JVM. https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/run_debug_japps.htm#NBDAG818

Comment: True, it seems like your method of execution is not appropriate and hence the VM flag isn't getting set.

Comment: I tried that too, setting the JVM argument in the Project->Properties->Run. This is what you mean right?

Comment: @OutOfMind Yes it should be something like that. I could update the VM arguments in intelliJ and see it working. In your configuration edit and update the VM argument with `-XX:-CompactStrings`

Comment: Added the screenshot of what I am doing

Comment: How are you finding the value? When using a watch expression I see the correct behaviour.

Comment: I was trying to debug and see just the debug variables and it wasn't working. I also tried by adding a watch expression, still not working.

Comment: Two things to try: 1) add the -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal option as well.  This will print out all the flags for the JVM when it starts and will show whether the flag really is set as you think; 2) Try running the app from outside NetBeans (use the jar file in the dist directory of the project) and see if that works. That will at least show you where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem using a trivial "Hello World" Java application. However, toggling the **CompactStrings** feature in the project properties settings worked fine for me, and caused **COMPACT_STRINGS** to be set appropriately, so this is not a bug in NetBeans.

Although I am using the same version of Java (181) as you, I have a more recent Dev Build of NetBeans (Build 201709220002), and there are several discrepancies between my project properties screen and yours. For example, mine shows the **Runtime Platform** field but yours does not:

[image: Project Properties]

Something else to check is that you really do have the environment you expect. I find it easy to mess things up when multiple versions of Java and Netbeans are installed.

This is what I see when I do **Help -> About**:

[image]

If your environment looks fine then I can only suggest that you download the latest DEV Build of NetBeans and try again.